# HttpWebResponde formatar retorno

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte Código:

```
try
{
  public string ProcessAttachment(string fileInput)
  {
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://flnws001qae.nexxera.com:80/nexxeraws/v2/SkylineWSv2");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    req.ContentType = "multipart/related; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"teste\"; boundary=\"----=_Part_72_348989292.1565031692584\"";
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
    req.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");
    //req.ContentLength = 1854;
    req.Host = "flnws001qae.nexxera.com:80";
    req.UserAgent = "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)";        
    req.KeepAlive = true; 

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileInput, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fileStream.Close();
    Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream();
    memStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    memStream.Close();
    stm.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    stm.Close();
    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    stm = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stm);
    return r.ReadToEnd();
   }
 }
 catch (WebException ex)
 {
   string exMessage = ex.Message;
   throw ex;
  }
}
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno:

> O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (500) Erro Interno do Servidor.

Existe uma forma de buscar o retorno do WebService, por exemplo " Falha de autenticação!"
No soapui tenho o retorno:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
   <env:Fault>
     <faultcode xmlns:codeNS="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">codeNS:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>1090 - Falha de autenticação!</faultstring>
  </env:Fault>
 </env:Body>
 </env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ter mais detalhes do erro/fault retornados, o `WebException` tem um objeto `Response`, que tem mais informações do que ocorreu na chamada do serviço.

Poderia testar se tem valor no Response e verificar as informações assim:

```
try
{
  // código que chama o serviço
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
   if (ex.Response != null)
   {
       var codigoErro    = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
       var descricaoErro = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
   } 
}
```

A documentação está aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception.response?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebException_Response

Quando é wcf tem uma forma de pegar diretamente o `faultexception` que pode funcionar também, mas não tenho certeza, então deixo aqui como uma alternativa pra ser testada:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
   var mensagemFault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
}
```